# using vba classes without using Microsoft VB editor

Tags: vba, class

Femap is an engineering simulation software that supports VBA. I am trying to use VBA that runs in Femap memory address using API programing application of Femap which is differnt from Microsoft IDE. I am wondering how I can use classes in VB without using Microsoft IDE

Comment: Thank you for responding. Femap and a number of other software use VBA for their automation. These applications have there own development environment which is different than Microsoft IDE for VBA that comes up when you press Alt_F11. In a lot of these application you can't create a class by inserting a module class. There is only one source file and all classes should be defined in that source file. I can use type, and end type to mimic a class in that file but I don't know how to use a class. I tried public class classname, some code, end class, but this is not the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I your question is some kind of misunderstandable. Let me point out what I understood:

- VBA is sold by Microsoft as part of application programming. This is exactly what can be seen in Office. When VBA is part of an application, you can use the IDE to directly work against the application.
- VBA is always COM. When you want to work against a library like the one of Femap you could also use Visual Studio 2013 and c#. You would have to create an Interop to work against Femap.
- You could also use Visual Studio 6 and work in VB (I dont mean VB.net). Some kind of oldschool ;-)
- Have a look onto this sample, unfortunately in German [Femap Tutorial API Programmierung mit Visual Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx-YOyAA1Us).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 2,000 page FEMAP API manual that defaults to the "pdf" folder in your install directory. As for getting things going in a FEMAP session, your easiest approach is:

(first install the type library, instructions are in API documentation)

```
Option explicit

Dim App as femap.model
set App = GetObject( , "femap.model")
'OR,  set App = CreateObject( , "femap.model") to CREATE a femap session.. etc.
```

And you are in. As for doing stuff, create objects and get to work!! Sets are the most important for manipulating things...

```
' Declare / set variable for freebody and element set objects
Dim fsE As femap.Set
Set fsE = App.feSet
```

---> and most data shoots back and forth as variants or arrays that are easily user manipulated....

```
Dim numID as long
Dim vArray as variant

    fsE.Clear
    rc = fsE.AddArray(numID, vArray)
    If ffb.SetNodes(True, rc) = FE_OK Then
        rc = ffb.SetElements(True, fsE.ID)
    End If
```

as for embedding your own applications and whatnot the approach is similar with most other VB windows programs... see the documentation.